# Socket connect() function explanation in C++/ Reference operator and Pointers

Tags: c++, c, sockets, pointers, pass-by-reference

I'm new to programming and would like a better understanding of this socket function connect(). I've read many descriptions but I couldn't understand this syntax:

```
int connect(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr,socklen_t addrlen)
```

Description: The addr argument is a pointer to a structure specifying the address to which this socket is to be bound.

This is part of my studying code:

```
  connect(socket_desc ,( struct sockaddr *) &server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
```

Can anyone explain why there is a structure in parentheses with a pointer operator and the reference operator after it?

Comment: The stuff inside () is a typecast; the & is the address-of operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anyone explain why there is a structure in parentheses with a pointer operator and the reference operator after it?

The parenthesis are being used for a **type cast**, and the ampersand is the **address-of operator**.  The code is obtaining the memory address of a struct variable, likely a `sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6` but could be any `sockaddr`-compatible struct, and then type-casting that memory address to a `sockaddr` pointer.

Sockets support many different types of addressing schemes, and there is a different `sockaddr_...` struct type defined for each of them. But the socket API functions that deal with addresses only accept `sockaddr*` parameters, so type-casting is needed.

Comment: struct sockaddr_in server;
if (connect(socket_desc ,( struct sockaddr *) &server , sizeof(server));
....

Can you give me a example of another way I could do without the type cast?

Comment: The only way to avoid the type-cast is to use a `union` instead. Put a `sockaddr` and `sockaddr_in` inside a union, then populate the `sockaddr_in` as needed, then use the `&` operator to pass the memory address of the `sockaddr`: `union {sockaddr addr; sockaddr_in ipv4;} server; server.ipv4.sin_addr = ...; connect(socket_desc, &server.addr, sizeof(server))`

Answer (score 1):

The `( struct sockaddr *) &server` part of that line can be described in English as:

Take the address of the object `server`, and treat that memory address (or pointer) as if it were a pointer to a `sockaddr` object.

The `&` operator, at least in this context, is taking the memory address of the identifier that follows.  An expression that is preceded by `(type)` is 'cast' to that type.  In C, that is the only form of type casting.  C++ inherits that functionality, but is discouraged in most C++ code in favor of the other casting operations (static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast, reinterpret_cast).